# Magento : Attribute Value and Code

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes

I have generate XML file using Product list, there are sections called `AttributeValueCode` and `AttributeValueLabel`.

Want to get **Label and Value(id)** for the **options** of **attribute having type select**

Any one have idea about this ?

Comment: do you mean attribute code and attribute label?

Comment: No. if color is black , have to get its code? is it possible?

Comment: I found this, This should be the answer for my question ? $attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('size');
    if ($attr->usesSource()) {
        echo $color_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId("10");
    }

Comment: how can you get the color id from size attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find below code

```
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color'); //"color" is the attribute_code

$allOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true);
foreach ($allOptions as $instance) {
    $id = $instance['value']; //id of the option
    $value = $instance['label']; //Label of the option
}
```

For product

```
$id=$product->getColor();
$value=$product->getAttributeText('color')
```

Comment: This is working .How can I get product base attribute. labels and values.

Comment: @ssk8323 find updated code

Comment: I customized and found a solution using following method Its works for me, thanks for your time and help, 
$attr = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attrname);
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    return $color_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId($attrvalue);
}